# Drupal 8 list taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal

What is best way to retrieve Drupal 8 taxonomy terms and pass array to twig template?

Now I have:

In template.theme

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    $variables['some_term'] = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree('some_term', $parent = 0, $max_depth = NULL, $load_entities = FALSE);

}
```

Now in page.html.twig I can access {{ some_term }} array.

I feel that something is wrong about this. What is the best way to achieve this? I just need an array of selected taxonomy terms in page.html.twig. I want to use it to build custom HTML code.

Equivalent function in Wordpress is simple get_terms().

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK.

Please check next:

- Are you getting taxonomy tree array values in template_preprocess_page?

  - If not ($variables['some_term'] should not be empty array)
    check if you are loading correct vocabulary with "...->loadTree('machine_name_of_vocabulary'..."
  - If yes check what twig is getting in page.html.twig You can check with: {{ dump(some_term) }}. Probably you will need to process array to get only for example list of term names.
- Did you cleared Drupal cache?